# Error in CreatingAppServicePlan when using az webapp up

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

[image: stops after none, not sure why]

stops after none, I was able to run this last week and now i get this error.

Comment: Could you please share the command which you are trying and the error in the text format.

Answer (score 0):

First need to login to cli for that use the following command and then give the credentials of your subscription to login.

```
az login
```

Now using the az command created an app service plan by following code and replace the resource group name and plan name by and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/appservice/plan?view=azure-cli-latest#az-appservice-plan-create):

code:

```
az appservice plan create --resource-group sa**** --name samp****
```

And got the following output
[image]

Now by using the following this [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-upcommand):
az webapp up created the web app by changing run time and using the plan service.

```
az webapp up --resource-group --plan --name --runtime "*****"
```

To create web app in azure portal with specific run time this code can be used with the specific runtime.

```
az webapp create -g ***** -p sa*** -n sam*** --runtime "node:12LTS"
```

Change the above resource group name and service plan and run time which used in local path, this creates web app to deploy code from local path to app and got the following output.

[image]